# Notepad++ "Move to Other View" moves left, not right

Tags: notepad++

This is a stupid question, but for the life of me I can't figure it out...
In notepad++, until recently, whenever I chose to move a tab to a the "other view", it would create a separate view on the right and move that tab there.

Now, for some reason, it creates the 'other view' on the LEFT of the other tabs, and moves the new tab there.  I can't seem to locate the setting that controls this, and I don't think I've changed anything in that regard.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may have closed all the files that were still on the left side so you were left with just the right side, then tried to move documents on the right side. Notepad++ remembers that you're still looking at the "right side" so the "other view" now refers to the one on the left.

Notepad++ will remember this even across launches if you have configured it to remember its sessions. You can reset it by closing all documents, or by closing Notepad++, deleting the sessions.xml file, and restarting it.

Comment: Aha!  You're right.  Once I closed all of the other tabs and moved my contents to the new one on the left I was able to open the 'other view' on the right.  Good catch!

Answer (score 12):

I've had the same problem multiple times, and I found this in Notepad++'s documentation: We can right-click on the bar dividing the two views, and select whether we want to rotate right/left. Since I only wanted to switch the two views (similar to your situation), rotating twice solves it. It helps a lot when you have a bunch of files open and don't want to close them!

Source:
http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Multiple_Views